# How do I extract raw data from plot element in R

Tags: r, plot

I use a method from a package to create a scatter plot

```
p <- noisePlot(data.frame)
```

Yet I wish to know the raw values created(/plotted) by this function.. any ideas?

P.S. the package not using gglot2, but the basic plot function in R

Comment: please add the `package` with `noisePlot` function as well as a reproducible example.

Comment: the package is named QDNAseq, but it's hard to reproduce without genetic information as input.. this is just a scatter plot in the end

Comment: it is very easy to create a reproducible example just hit `?noisePlot` and copy/paste the example to your question. `data(LGG150);
readCounts <- LGG150;
readCountsFiltered <- applyFilters(readCounts);
readCountsFiltered <- estimateCorrection(readCountsFiltered);
noisePlot(readCountsFiltered)`

Comment: I'm not sure about this package in specific, but `p$` in RStudio should show everything inside the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoy can get the noisePlot function:

```
findMethods(noisePlot)$`QDNAseqReadCounts#missing`
```

And editing it get the data as output:

```
dataNoisePlot <- function (x, y, main = "Noise Plot", adjustIncompletes = TRUE, 
                      fit = NULL, sdFUN = "sdDiffTrim", xAxis = c("average reads per bin", 
                                                                  "reciprocal of average reads per bin", "total reads"), 
                      ...) 
  {
    if (is.character(sdFUN) && sdFUN == "sdDiffTrim") {
      symbol <- quote(hat(sigma)[Delta^"*"]^2)
    }
    else if (is.character(sdFUN) && length(grep("Diff", 
                                                sdFUN)) == 1) {
      symbol <- quote(hat(sigma)[Delta]^2)
    }
    else {
      symbol <- quote(hat(sigma)^2)
    }
    sdFUN <- getAnywhere("sdDiffTrim")[[2]][[1]]
    condition <- getAnywhere("binsToUse")[[2]][[1]](x)
    counts <- getAnywhere("assayDataElement")[[2]][[1]](x, "counts")[condition, 
                                            , drop = FALSE]
    usedReads <- colSums(counts)
    if (adjustIncompletes) {
      counts <- counts/getAnywhere("fData")[[2]][[1]](x)$bases[condition] * 100L
      counts[getAnywhere("fData")[[2]][[1]](x)$bases[condition] == 0] <- 0L
    }
    reciprocalOfAverageUsedReadsPerBin <- getAnywhere("expectedVariance")[[2]][[1]](x)
    if (is.null(fit)) {
      if (!"fit" %in% getAnywhere("assayDataElementNames")[[2]][[1]](x)) 
        x <- getAnywhere("estimateCorrection")[[2]][[1]](x)
      fit <- getAnywhere("assayDataElement")[[2]][[1]](x, "fit")[condition, 
                                        , drop = FALSE]
    }
    signal <- counts/fit
    signal[fit <= 0] <- 0
    noise <- apply(signal, 2, sdFUN, na.rm = TRUE)

    out <- data.frame(reciprocalOfAverageUsedReadsPerBin, noise^2)
    return(out)
  }

dataNoisePlot(readCountsFiltered)
       reciprocalOfAverageUsedReadsPerBin    noise.2
LGG150                         0.02804484 0.02833476
```

Comment: Thanks! great idea.. for some reason I get this error:  `Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'sdDiffTrim' of mode 'function' was not found `

Comment: Have you loaded the QDNAseq package?? I am using QDNAseq version 1.16.0, and I get the function without problem, is this: function (x, ..., trim = 0.001, scale = TRUE) {if (scale) {x <- x/mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)}; sdDiff(x, ..., trim = trim)}

Comment: I got this working.. I guess I had some small error somewhere but when I copied your function from above it worked.. thanks!